# Too many countries in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, yaxis

if someone could please help me, when I run the code bellow, it works, but there are too many countries in the graph, and the labels overlap so I wanted to:

a) learn any way to "stretch" the yaxis to that the country lines can be a bit more distant from one another, and consequently, the labels won’t overlap,

b) learn how to set a margin inside the graph, so that all the names from all the countries can fit in the graph frame (they are currently being cut).

```
    r <- ggplot(df3, aes(x=year2, y=df_ji, colour=Country)) +
         geom_line() + 
         scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none')  + 
         geom_dl(aes(label=Country), method = 
         list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points"), cex = 1.0)) +
         stat_summary(aes(y = df_ji, group=1), fun.y=mean, colour= "blue", 
         geom="line", alpha = .8, size = 1.5) +
         theme_bw(base_size = 18, base_family = "serif") +
         labs(title = "Judicial Independence across Latin America", x = 
         "Year", y = "Judicial Independence") 

    r + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, it is hard to discern what exactly it is that you want since you haven't posted the data or your plot output. It would be easier for us to help if you edited your post accordingly. That being said, have a look at the `ggrepel` package. If you install it and then run `geom_text_repel` in place of `geom_text`, problem B might have already been taken care of

Comment: As mentioned it would be useful to provide a minimal dataset with the code above.  Running  `dput(head(df3,5))` and pasting the result into the question would help people reproduce your plots.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I corrected a bit the code above and added a picture of my current graph. 
For the graph frame problem, I tried to add years for which I don’t have data, with the command "xlim". Then the graph looks much nicer, but instead of giving me gridlines from 2 to 2 years it gives me from 5 to 5, which is not what I want.
"geom_text" doesn’t work as replacement for "geom_dl" in this case because it labels every point in time, whereas I only want to label each line.